# Inserting items manually when using FirestorePagingAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am using FirestorePagingAdapter to list images from Firestore Database. I want to insert native Ad objects into the list before setting it to Recycler view so that Ads will be placed in between images. I already have the code to create native ads and insert them into the list. But since I am using FirestorePagingAdapter, how can I modify the list before setting it to RecyclerView.

```
    Query query = db.collection("Wallpapers")
                        .whereEqualTo("category", mCategoryName).orderBy("uploadedDate", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                        .setPrefetchDistance(2)
                        .setPageSize(10)
                        .build();


                FirestorePagingOptions<WallpaperResponse> firestorePagingOptions = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<WallpaperResponse>()
                        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                        .setQuery(query, config, WallpaperResponse.class)
                        .build();

                firestorePagingAdapter = new FirestorePagingAdapter<WallpaperResponse, WallpaperViewHolder>(firestorePagingOptions){

                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public WallpaperViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
                                switch (viewType) {
                               /* case NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
                                    View unifiedNativeLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(
                                            viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.native_ad,
                                            viewGroup, false);
                                    return new NativeAdViewHolder(unifiedNativeLayoutView);*/
                                    case WALLPAPER_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
                                        // Fall through.
                                    default:
                                        View menuItemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                                                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_wallpapers_item_grid, viewGroup, false);
                                        return new WallpaperViewHolder(menuItemLayoutView);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WallpaperViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull WallpaperResponse model) {
                                loadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
                                switch (viewType) {
                            /*case NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
                                UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd = (UnifiedNativeAd) mWallpapers.get(position);
                                populateNativeAdView(unifiedNativeAd, ((NativeAdViewHolder) holder).getAdView());
                                break;*/
                                    case WALLPAPER_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
                                        // fall through
                                    default:
                                        holder.favAnimation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        holder.mode.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        holder.author.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        WallpaperHelper wallpaperHelper = new WallpaperHelper();
                               ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(model.getThumbUrl(), new ImageViewAware(holder.image),
                                                mOptions.build(), new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                                                        super.onLoadingStarted(imageUri, view);
                                                        int color;
                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                                                        super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
                                                    }
                                                }, null);

                                }

                                holder.card.setOnClickListener(v -> {

                                });
                            }
                        };

firestorePagingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(Utils.getAnimationAdapter(firestorePagingAdapter));


     private void insertAdsInWallpaperItems() {
            if (unifiedNativeAds.size() <= 0) {
                return;
            }

            int offset = (wallpaperList.size() / unifiedNativeAds.size()) + 1;
            int index = 0;
            for (UnifiedNativeAd ad : unifiedNativeAds) {
                if(index != 0){
                    wallpaperList.add(index, ad);
                }
                index = index + offset;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the question? What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Currently, whatever data returned from query is set automatically to recyeclerView using FirestorePagingOptions and FirestorePagingAdapter. I would like to modify the data returned from Firestore to insert native Ads in between, and then load this modified data in recycler view. I need to access this data before setting it in the adapter

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below. Although, it does not alter the original list size, it can help you squeeze the ad data into one of your list items.

```
firestorePagingOptions.value = FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<Story>()
                .setQuery(factsQuery, Source.DEFAULT, config) {
                    val story = it.toObject(Story::class.java)!!
                    //Modify your data here
                    story //return the modified object 
                }.build()
```